# My Button to clear all input fields wont work

Tags: javascript, html

i made a list where u can input the amount of a product u want to buy and it cauculates the price for. I am trying to make a button that clears all input fields when pressed i dont want the input fields to be cleared when cauculated only when the delete button is pressed. I tried testing it for one button but i cant get it to work can anyone help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Waschlotion</td>
      <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haarshampoo</td>
      <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bodylotion</td>
      <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
      <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deospray</td>
     <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Zahnbürste</td>
   <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
  <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
<button  onclick="document.getElementById(MullkompressenAmount).value = ''">Löschen</button>
</body>
<script>
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 3.20;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 1.50;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;

let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmount;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;
let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount;
let MullkompressenAmount;



function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
  (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
  (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
  (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
  (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = Sum;
}


 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: typo: `document.getElementById(MullkompressenAmount).value` - you forgot the quote marks round the id. You'll need to escape them though, if you insist on writing this code inline within the HTML element (hint: don't do that, just make it call a function which then clears the field. Also, you need to make it clear all the fields. not just one! Consider using a class selector and then looping through them. Or make it a form and use the built-in reset button type).

Comment: Element classes and a couple of loops would help reduce the code footprint immensely.

Comment: If you wrapped this into an actual form, then you could simply use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your **tag Id** into ''.
Try the below code for the reset button.

```
<button
  onclick="document.getElementById('MullkompressenAmount').value = ''"
>
  Löschen
</button>
```

Comment: will do wont let me do it for 3 more mins dw tho i wont forget :D

Answer (score 1):

In `document.getElementById` you forgot to add `` to the `MullkompressenAmount` id.

Fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Waschlotion</td>
      <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haarshampoo</td>
      <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bodylotion</td>
      <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
      <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deospray</td>
     <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Zahnbürste</td>
   <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
  <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
<button  onclick="document.getElementById(`MullkompressenAmount`).value = ''">Löschen</button>
</body>
<script>
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 3.20;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 1.50;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;

let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmount;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;
let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount;
let MullkompressenAmount;



function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
  (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
  (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
  (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
  (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = Sum;
}


 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your input values to null.

```js
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 3.20;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 1.50;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;


let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }


  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
  (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
  (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
  (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
  (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = Sum;
}

function ClearAll(){

    console.log("clicked")
    document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value="";    
    document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value="";    
    document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value="";   
    document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value="";    
    document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value="";    
    document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value="";
    document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value=""; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Waschlotion</td>
      <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haarshampoo</td>
      <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bodylotion</td>
      <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
      <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deospray</td>
     <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Zahnbürste</td>
   <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
  <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
<button  onclick="ClearAll()">Löschen</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo while you are resetting the value.
you need to wrap your id in quotes (' or ") but you are using " as outer quotes so you need to wrap your id in single quote (') like **('MullkompressenAmount')**

To reset the all input fields, please use `<input type="reset" />` which you can trigger on form using JS as well. Please visit MDN for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('MullkompressenAmount').value = ''">Löschen</button>
```

*EDIT*: **Please use form tag to use `<input type="reset" />`**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the value of all inputs in your form, you can use this. If you want to limit you can use the not function

```js
function Clear() {
 $('input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Waschlotion</td>
      <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haarshampoo</td>
      <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bodylotion</td>
      <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
      <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deospray</td>
     <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Zahnbürste</td>
   <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
  <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><p id="Sum"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
<button  onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a lot by using 1) [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the prices (instead of having separate variables for them), and 2) [class attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) to target the inputs instead of separate ids. You can then perform a simple calculation with [a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and use the same technique to empty all the inputs when you click the "delete" button.

```js
// Cache the elements
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
const calculateBtn = document.querySelector('.calculate');
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete');
const sum = document.querySelector('.sum');

// Add event listeners to the buttons that call their
// corresponding functions
calculateBtn.addEventListener('click', handleCalculate);
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', handleDelete);

function handleCalculate() {

  // Initialise a temporary variable to hold the sum
  // which increases on each iteration of the loop
  let tempsum = 0;

  // Loop over the product (input) elements
  // we cached earlier
  for (const product of products) {

    // Get the input value.
    const value = product.value;

    // Get the price from the input's dataset
    const price = product.dataset.price;

    // Multiply them (coercing them to Numbers first)
    // and add them to our temporary sum variable
    tempsum += Number(value) * Number(price);
  }

  // Finally add that sum to the sum element
  sum.textContent = tempsum.toFixed(2);
}

// `handleDelete` also uses a loop, except on each
// iteration it resets each input's value to an empty string,
// and then does the same for the sum element
function handleDelete() {
  for (const product of products) {
    product.value = '';
  }
  sum.textContent = '';
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #ababab; margin-bottom: 1em; }
.heading { background-color: #787878; color: white; }
th, td { padding: 0.3em 0.3em; }
.sum { display: inline; }
.buttons { margin-top: 1em; }
button { display: inline; margin-right: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="heading">
    <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
    <th>Menge</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waschlotion</td>
    <td><input class="product" data-price="1.30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haarshampoo</td>
    <td><input class="product" data-price="1.50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bodylotion</td>
    <td><input class="product" data-price="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
    <td><input class="product" data-price="4.80"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deospray</td>
    <td><input class="product" data-price="1.80"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Sum: <div class="sum"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="calculate">Rechnen</button>
  <button class="delete">Löschen</button>
</buttons>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)